# Восстановление менеджера рабочего стола Lubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, lubuntu, lxde

Новичок в линуксе. Воспользовавшись инструкцией, решил при последнем запуске системы внести гугл драйв в автозагрузку. Это был последний корректный запуск системы. Позже на форуме прочитал, что лубунту крайне плохо относится автозагрузке - она от этого портится. К сожалению, описанные [здесь](https://lubuntu.ru/viewtopic.php?t=2032) процедуры не помогли.

Можно ли как-нибудь отремонтировать систему без переустановки?

Answer (score 0):

Ларчик просто открывался. Дано: черный экран и возможность открыть контекстное меню правой клавишей мыши.

**Решение**:

1. Открываем файловый менеджер

2. Открываем вкладку Перейти-Приложения-параметры-Приложения по умолчанию для LXSession

3. Удаляем всё лишнее (можно по очереди с перезагрузкой - тогда поймем что нам испортило жизнь.

Аллилуйя - всё вернулось на круги своя.